# Aptana Studio 3 Syntax Errors Unexpected Tokens

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error, aptana3

```html
<body>
  <p>Count numbers:
    <output id="result"></output>
  </p>
  <button onclick="startWorker()">Start Worker</button>
  <button onclick="stopWorker()">Stop Worker</button>
  <br />
  <br />

  <script>
    var w;

    function startWorker() {
      if (typeofWorker) !== "undefined") {
      if (typeof(w) == "undefined") {
        w = new Worker("demo_workers.js");

      }
      w.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
      };
    } else {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry! No Web Worker support.";
    }
    }

    function stopWorker() {
      w.terminate();
      w = undefined;
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

I have been teaching myself Html5 on the w3schools website. While trying to replicate the web workers .js tutorial, I keep getting errors in the  section saying: Syntax Error: Unexpected Token "!==" on one line and Syntax Error: Unexpected Token "else". I can't seem to find out why, also I've compared my code to the original on the site and everything is the same. Any help will be appreciated.

THe problems are the second line of the first function ( the !== ) and the else further down are being flagged as unexpected tokens.

```js
var i = 0;

function timedCount() {
  i = i + 1;
  postMessage(i);
  setTimeout("timedCount()", 500);

}

timedCount();
```

This is the .js for the html above.

Comment: Can you share your code so we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

I feel kind of stupid...just reviewed my code and found a missing parenthesis in the first if statemeent of the first function in the html script. Goes to show that taking a break and coming back to review your  code can solve many problems.